# python code to write in csv in table format

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

```
[('01', ['name abc', 'age 32', 'address addr123']), ('02', ['name def', 'age 22', 'address addr456'])]
```

I want this list to be written in CSV file in below format. Some time list may contain more values.So no hard codings.
    Expected output in csv in table format

```
id   name  age   address
01   abc   32    addr123
02   def   22    addr456
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: im nt able to get the idea itself.

Comment: Do you know what the C in CSV stands for?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

data = [('01', ['name abc', 'age 32', 'address addr123']), ('02', ['name def', 'age 22', 'address addr456 789'])]

with open(path_to_csv, 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, 'id name age address'.split())
    writer.writeheader()
    for row_id, rest in data:
        row = {'id': row_id}
        for item in rest:
            key, value = item.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
            row[key] = value
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I always use pandas for anything like this, so I'm genuinely curious - does csv cope gracefully with different length lines? for example in the question he mentions that there might be more headers in other records - if there was a new record added with a different field, would your code cope with that?

Comment: @Stael no it doesn't, but OP would have to specify how additional fields are handled. What if they need to be in a certain order?

Comment: there are ways to order columns in pandas - mostly I find that it doesn't matter. I would say coping with unexpected/missing data is more important than ordering columns, but that is just an opinion.

Comment: OrderedDict([('01', ['name abc', 'age 32', 'address addr123']), ('02', ['name def', 'age 22', 'address addr456'])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 117, in <module>
    key, value = item.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @nishanth sounds like one of your strings doesn't have spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

alternately, you could use `pandas`, which can definitely cope with different row lengths eg:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('01', ['name abc', 'age 32', 'address addr123']),
        ('02', ['name def', 'age 22'])] # example of a shorter row



df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i:{a.split()[0]:a.split()[1] for a in j} for i,j in data},
            orient='index')

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

EDIT:  This does assume that you never have a space in your values ie nothing like

```
('01', ['name ghi jkl', 'age 42', 'address addr123'])
```

but i think that's true of all the answers so far.

Comment: OrderedDict([('01', ['name abc', 'age 32', 'address addr123']), ('02', ['name def', 'age 22', 'address addr456'])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 114, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i:{a.split()[0]:a.split()[1] for a in j} for i,j in mydict},
  File "test.py", line 114, in <dictcomp>
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i:{a.split()[0]:a.split()[1] for a in j} for i,j in mydict},
  File "test.py", line 114, in <dictcomp>
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i:{a.split()[0]:a.split()[1] for a in j} for i,j in mydict},
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: thanks  all found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that column name will be sorted. eg name will  always appear first in column. Below code will work fine. Also you don't need any extra library.

```
arr = [('01', ['name abc', 'age 32', 'address addr123']), ('02', ['name def', 'age 22', 'address addr456'])]
columnName = ["id"]
output = []
for l in arr:
    ID = l[0]
    val = l[1]
    line = str(ID) + '\t'
    for x in val:
        y = x.split(' ')
        if y[0] not in columnName:
            columnName.append(y[0])
        line += str(y[1]) + '\t'
    line += '\n'
    output.append(line)

colLine = ''
for i in columnName:
    colLine += str(i) + '\t'
colLine += '\n'
output = [colLine] + output
f = open("output.csv", 'w')
for x in output:
    f.write(x)
f.close()
```

Comment: OrderedDict([('01', ['name abc', 'age 32', 'address addr123']), ('02', ['name def', 'age 22', 'address addr456'])])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 123, in <module>
    line += str(y[1]) + '\t'
IndexError: list index out of range